# Should I be worried that my pelvis pops during leg raises?

Tags: exercise

When I do leg raises I feel a slight pop around where my right leg connects to my pelvic region.  It's been this way for years. It doesn't hurt and this exercise is the only thing that causes it. In general, I tend to avoid leg raises so this isn't a big issue, but I'm wondering if it's something I should be worried about.

Comment: Are you describing a [snapping in front of the hip](http://www.moveforwardpt.com/SymptomsConditionsDetail.aspx?cid=ce73393a-f583-4960-9eed-a6fcae984ea2#.U-5crKPOv9g)?  If so, a visit to a therapist could give you an evaluation and specifics to stretch your  tight muscles and strengthen your weak muscles to help reduce the chances of snapping.

Comment: That could be what I have, but the article seems to indicate that you get it from being injured.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it sounds to you like you have a snapping hip you can [read more here](http://orthoinfo.aaos.org/topic.cfm?topic=A00363) and see [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4096/snapping-hip-syndrome-and-running) for more answers.   Tightness and repetitive motions can cause the tendons or hip to snap quite loudly.

If you have pain or weakness be sure to have it checked out by your doctor and/or physical therapist.  Since you say that you don't have any pain with the snapping, you could try  stretches and foam rolling to help reduce the tightness.

- **Front of Hip**

  If the snapping is in the front of your hip, you would want to stretch your hip flexors:
  [Psoas](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6076/could-someone-explain-this-psoas-stretch/6078#6078) and [Rectus Femoris](http://youtu.be/X7K9YUuhygM?t=35s) and [foam roll the front of your thigh](http://youtu.be/FGBjcu8yycg?t=1m50s) and hip.
- **Outer Side of Hip**

  If the snapping is on the outer side, see [ITB](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3337/how-to-properly-stretch-your-iliotibial-band/3404#3404) stretches and foam rolling.
- **Back of Hip**

  If the snapping is in the back of the hip, you would stretch and foam roll the [hamstrings](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/576/how-can-i-stretch-hamstrings-in-isolation/3940#3940).

If you have swelling or tenderness you can consider rest, ice and an over the counter anti-inflammatory if appropriate for you. Also if you feel you have alignment problems, tightness or weakness of the pelvic, hip, thigh or core muscles, you could have an evaluation from an orthopedic or sports physical therapist to get specific exercise recommendations to address your imbalances.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue for years. Today I found that using the technique here eliminates my hip clicking (and for may others according to the YouTube comments):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qRRLTQqqFCA.

The basic idea is:

- Don't arch your lower back at any point throughout the leg raises (keep it hollow).
- Keep your pelvis locked in position (don't tilt as you go up/down).

It seems that leg raises performed with poor form bring can out the hip popping in a lot of people.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no pain or obvious weirdness surrounding the phenomenon other than a popping noise, you should be in the clear. I have this with my knees and my doctor said it's no problem unless there's pain. Any sort of stress or pressure on a joint can cause popping, but this isn't necessarily an indicator of damage on its own.

Have some links:

- http://www.livestrong.com/article/434645-why-do-my-joints-crack-when-im-lifting-weights/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cracking_joints
- http://stronglifts.com/squats-cracking-joints-knees-healthy/