# adductor / hamstring weirdness in the bottom of squat

Tags: squats, barbell, tendons, hamstring

I've been squatting for several years and have done regional level competitions and some quasi-formal training and coaching. Normally I can get any additional answers I need from other fitness friends books by guys like Pendlay and Rippetoe.

Recently I've started getting a pain-less popping sensation in my adductor magnus area. No idea if that's the muscle it's really coming from, but it's in the triangle between my hamstring, adductor, and glute, one just one side.

It feels a bit like some muscles are moving around on top of each other.

It doesn't happen constantly, it doesn't hurt, and it doesn't seem to affect anything. It only happens in the bottom of the squat ("the hole").

Does anyone have any references to a common fitness injury or mobility issue that could be going on?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapping_hip_syndrome  It would seem a tendon is just a little out of place and snaps back into places in "the hole"

Comment: @TimothyPuffer you know it's funny I read briefly about "snapping hip syndrome" but because it felt like more of a hamstring thing I ruled it out. I'll keep reading up on it and pay more attention over the next couple of days.

Comment: @Eric, this q/a has some more info on [snapping hip](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18626/should-i-be-worried-that-my-pelvis-pops-during-leg-raises/18637#18637) that may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't verify it, but I don't think it was [snapping hip syndrome (SHS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapping_hip_syndrome). Everything about SHS is related to the hip joint itself, and mine was much more in the hamstring-adductor area.

I'm not sure exactly what fixed it, but I went at it from a few angles and haven't had the issue for a couple of weeks now.

- Light-ish [good mornings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good-morning) once a week. 65% of bodyweight barbell, knees not totally locked, but really trying to isolate the hamstrings as much as possible. These in particular really made my hamstrings feel great and I was able to ramp up the weight quickly to around 75%. 3x8 - 3x10.
- [Forward-bend type yoga pose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uttanasana), legs straight, trying to jam my butt into the top corner of the room.
- The rest of my Madcow 5x5 program.

I google'd around a bit and found other folks talking about [hamstring tendons sliding around on their femur](http://forum.bodybuilding.com/showthread.php?t=143506913), and the general approach seems to be stretch and strengthen, like normal.

Those both worked fine for me and as a bonus the increased hamstring flexibility has really helped me lower my squat depth.